# c# split text file by changing the line number

Tags: regex, string, c#-4.0, text

I'm trying to split text file by line numbers,
for example, if I have text file like:

```
1 ljhgk uygk uygghl \r\n
1 ljhg kjhg kjhg kjh gkj  \r\n
1 kjhl kjhl kjhlkjhkjhlkjhlkjhl  \r\n
2 ljkih lkjhl kjhlkjhlkjhlkjhl  \r\n
2 lkjh lkjh lkjhljkhl  \r\n
3 asdfghjkl  \r\n
3 qweryuiop  \r\n
```

I want to split it to 3 parts (1,2,3),
How can I do this? the size of the text is very large (~20,000,000 characters) and I need an efficient way (like regex).

Answer (score 1):

Another idea, you can use linq to get the groups you're after, by splitting by each first word. Note that this will take each first word, so make sure you only have numbers there. This is using the split/join antipattern, but it seems to work nice here.

```
var lines = from line in s.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), 
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            let lineNumber = line.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), 2).FirstOrDefault()
            group line by lineNumber
            into g
            select String.Join("\n", g);
```

Notes:

- [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) is gurenteed to return lines in the order they appeared.
- If a block appears more than once (e.g. `"1 1 2 2 3 3 1"`), all blocks with the same number will be merged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex, but Split will not work too well. You can Match for the following pattern:

```
^(\d).*$          # Match first line, capture number
([\r\n]+^\1.*$)*  # Match additional lines that begin with the same number
```

Example: [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=5a0d4f18-8e2c-46e1-b661-c3e38d405c68)

I did try to split by`$(?<=^(\d+).*)[\r\n]+^(?!\1)`, but it adds the line numbers as additional elementnt in the array.